# Access methods inside a list of a class

Tags: java, class, arraylist

Sorry for the missleading title but I really don't know how to explain my problem.

Lets say I have two clases, the first one Car **(without gets and sets in the example)**

```
public class Car{
    int id;
    string model;
    ArrayList<Specs> ListSpecs = new ArrayList<Specs>();
}
```

The second one, Specs, contains further details of the car:

```
public class Specs{
    float kilometers;
    float passangers;
    public float km_pass(float a, float b){
            return this.a/this.b;
       }
}
```

Now my main question is, how could I access the variable km_pass from an object type  Car? Tried something like

```
Example  Car = new Car();
Car.setId(123);
Car.setModel("Abc");
ListDetails Specs = new Specs();
Car.SetSpecs(ListDetails);

Car.SetSpecs.SetKilometers(123); //wont work
```

Is my example clear enough?

Thanks!

Comment: Give the class getters/setters

Comment: It is a list, so you have to specify an index.

Comment: Even if I had a method iside the class Specs SetKilometers, as said in the cde(getters and setters arent included) the last line of the example wnt work, can you give an example of how'd I have to do it?

Comment: Your question isn't at all clear, because you're referring to `SetSpecs` without letting us know what it is.  Also, you've given us a lot of Java code that doesn't compile (you made `ListDetails` look like a type and then referred to it like a variable).  Please post code that compiles, or at least code that compiles except for the specific problem you're asking about.

Comment: Why does Car contain a List of Specs instead of just a Spec object?

Comment: @TrevorFreeman Imagine there are more objects, I just tired to simplify the code. Overall all I want to add is a method inside a list that is isnide an object.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "a method inside a list"?  Do you want to run a method for all items in the list?  Create your own list type with a new method?  Or just access a single element from the list?  If it is the last one, then you just need to specify an index as @ElDuderino said above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're dealing with a list here, it is important to note that the list is an entirely different object from those contained inside it.

I suppose you're thinking about the list as a (printed) page of a menu where if you want to change an item you must change the entire page, this is incorrect. Think of the list as a cabinet if you want to change an object inside it, you don't change the whole cabinet, just the item inside a drawer.

---

How does this apply to your situation:
List, should be the cabinet.

Spec, should be the items inside the drawers (each position of the list is a drawer)

If your setSpecs method looks like this:

```
void setSpecs (List<Spec> specs) {
    this.listSpecs = specs;
}
```

It means that every time you call setSpecs you're actually changing the whole cabinet.

It is possible that you want to **add** a spec instead, it would look something like this:

```
void addSpec (Spec spec) {
    this.listSpecs.add(spec);
}
```

And to get a spec from the list would go like this:

```
// think of index as the number of the drawer where the spec is stored.
Spec getSpec (int index) {
    // actually gets the spec from the list
    return this.listSpecs.get(index)
}
```

and the example:

```
// Create a new car
Car car = new Car();
// Configures the car
car.setId(123);
car.setModel("Abc");
// Create a new spec
Spec spec = new Spec();
// Configures the spec
spec.setKilometers(123);
// Adds spec to the car's list
car.addSpec(spec);
// gets the first spec of the list
Spec firstSpec = car.getSpec(0);
```

Comment: Mhh I think this has helped me exactly to figure what I wanted! Thank you very much dude :)